# TIC READ ERROR in Mac OSX Sierra

Tags: macos

When I run my app on OSX 10.12, I see this error in the log, even though my app still functions normally:

```
error   11:31:23.274910 -0700   MyApp   TIC Read Error [76:0x6000001945d0]: 1:57
error   11:32:24.774500 -0700   MyApp   TIC Read Error [77:0x608000193590]: 1:57
error   11:33:24.903966 -0700   MyApp   TIC Read Error [79:0x61800018cd90]: 1:57
error   11:33:42.201840 -0700   MyApp   TIC Read Error [63:0x6000001911d0]: 1:57
error   11:33:42.201908 -0700   MyApp   TIC Read Error [70:0x6100001938d0]: 1:57
error   11:33:42.217283 -0700   MyApp   TIC Read Error [60:0x61800018df70]: 1:57
error   11:33:42.217388 -0700   MyApp   TIC Read Error [53:0x600000190cf0]: 1:57
error   11:33:42.338048 -0700   MyApp   TIC Read Error [66:0x618000192140]: 1:57
error   11:34:25.216051 -0700   MyApp   TIC Read Error [81:0x60800018c160]: 1:57
```

Googling shows a few people report this with other apps, but there's no explanation of what that error means. What does "TIC" mean in Sierra? "Trusted Internet Connection"? "Text Input Console"? "Tyrannosaurus Incoming Comet"?

Comment: There's too many TLA's (three-letter acronyms) these days...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is TIC Read Status 1:57 in iOS11/Xcode 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352735/what-is-tic-read-status-157-in-ios11-xcode-9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“TIC” expands to “TCP I/O connection”, which is a subsystem within CFNetwork that runs a TCP connection

Comment: Chances are 50/50 you're making that up, but I'm marking it the answer because it's better than anything I can come up with. ✅

Comment: @YusufX I believe it's from here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66058 (answered by "Apple Staff") More on the following numbers in the link

Comment: @YusufX have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352735/what-is-tic-read-status-157-in-ios11-xcode-9

Answer (score 1):

**TIC** stands for - **T**CP **I**/O **C**onnection

> “1” and “57” are the CFStreamError domain and code, respectively; a domain of 1 is kCFStreamErrorDomainPOSIX and, within that domain, 57 is ENOTCONN
>
> Beyond that, it’s important to realise that this ENOTCONN does not necessarily mean that anything has gone wrong.

Sources:

- https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/272678
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66058