# Hide logs from Xcode 9?

Tags: xcode9

When using the Xcode 9 and run application on simulator following logs appear

> [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1754 received sct extension length is less than sct data length
>
> TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the scheme's OS_ACTIVITY_MODE to 'Disable'?

[See answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46510266/1418981)

Comment: Setting `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE ` environment variable will disable `NSLog/os.log` as well :0. See comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46510266/1418981