# TIC Read Status [6:0x0]: 1:57 Xcode 9 - Network Requests not working

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift4, xcode9

I am trying to make standard Https calls to a web server and am getting TIC Read Status [6:0x0]: 1:57 very frequently and it is preventing webservices from working. Is anyone else having this issue?

Comment: You can find answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352735/what-is-tic-read-status-157-in-ios11-xcode-9

Comment: Apple needs to get there . together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TIC Read Error [476:0x60800018dc30]: 1:57**

OK, here’s how this breaks down:

- “TIC” expands to “TCP I/O connection”, which is a subsystem within CFNetwork that runs a TCP connection
- “Read Error” is pretty self explanatory
- “476” is a connection ID number within TIC; it’s not useful to us
- “0x60800018dc30” is a pointer to the TIC object itself; again it’s not useful to us
- “1” and “57” are the CFStreamError domain and code, respectively; a domain of 1 is kCFStreamErrorDomainPOSIX and, within that domain, 57 is ENOTCONN

In short, a TCP read has failed with ENOTCONN.

As the TCP I/O connection subsystem has no public API, you must necessarily be using it via some high-level wrapper (like NSURLSession).  What API is that?  Do you see the error manifest there?  If so, what’s does that error look like?

Hope this breakdown helps.