# TIC Read Status ios 11 xcode 9

Tags: xcode, nsurl, ios11

Incredible! Xcode 9 with iOS 11 present surprise again. Application work perfectly but thousand time i have this error on my log window. I just found one issue on stackoverflow with my problem but no one solve...please explain what is it because i have some scares.

```
2017-10-13 19:58:43.625919+0300 RadioClub[3509:895468] TIC Read Status [231:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-13 19:58:43.625988+0300 RadioClub[3509:895468] TIC Read Status [231:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-13 19:58:43.662070+0300 RadioClub[3509:894656] TIC Read Status [219:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-13 19:58:43.662136+0300 RadioClub[3509:894656] TIC Read Status [219:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-13 19:58:43.698135+0300 RadioClub[3509:894656] TIC Read Status [233:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-13 19:58:43.698204+0300 RadioClub[3509:894656] TIC Read Status [233:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-13 19:58:43.735485+0300 RadioClub[3509:894656] TIC Read Status [232:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-13 19:58:43.735579+0300 RadioClub[3509:894656] TIC Read Status [232:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-13 19:58:43.774531+0300 RadioClub[3509:895468] TIC Read Status [234:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-13 19:58:43.774599+0300 RadioClub[3509:895468] TIC Read Status [234:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-13 19:58:43.809913+0300 RadioClub[3509:894656] TIC Read Status [230:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-13 19:58:43.809984+0300 RadioClub[3509:894656] TIC Read Status [230:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-13 19:58:43.850549+0300 RadioClub[3509:894656] TIC Read Status [226:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-13 19:58:43.850623+0300 RadioClub[3509:894656] TIC Read Status [226:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-13 19:58:43.858837+0300 RadioClub[3509:895468] TIC Read Status [119:0x0]: 1:57
```

Answer (score 1):

refer answer at: [developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/90564#272678)
and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352735/what-is-tic-read-status-157-in-ios11-xcode-9?s=2%7C59.7783)