# How to get the raw JSON from an API call

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsurlsession

[**NOTE:** This has been edited for clarity since there seems to be some confusion about what I want.  I *only* want the raw JSON.  In this case, it should be `{"foo":"bar"}`. It is important to highlight that *I want this as a string*! I don't need it decoded into a Swift object or marshaled or modified in any way!]

Is it possible to get the raw JSON from an API call?  Currently I'm using `URLSession.dataTask(with:request)` but the response data includes the response header along with the body. I only want the raw JSON as it comes back to me, as a string.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
// Build the URL
var urlComponents = URLComponents()
urlComponents.scheme = "http"
urlComponents.host = "127.0.0.1"
urlComponents.port = 80
urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "foo", value: "bar")]
guard let url = urlComponents.url else {
    fatalError("Could not create URL from components")
}

// Configure the request
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(responseData, response, error) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("ERROR: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        guard let _ = response else {
            print("Data was not retrieved from request")
            return
        }

        print("JSON String: \(String(describing: String(data: responseData!, encoding: .utf8)))")

        if let resData = responseData {
            let jsonResponse = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: resData, options: [])

            if let response = jsonResponse as? [String: Any] {
                print("RESPONSE:")
                dump(response)
            } else {
                print("SOMETHING WENT WRONG")
            }
        }
    }
}

task.resume()
```

This produces the following in the console:

```
JSON String: Optional("HTTP/1.1 OK\nContent-Type: application/json\n\n{\"foo\":\"bar\"}")
SOMETHING WENT WRONG
```

Comment: Can you post some screenshots or code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll find the response body in the completion handler `Data` parameter. You decide what you want to do with it.

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (responseData, response, responseError) in
    guard responseData = responseData else { return }
    print("JSON String: \(String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8))")
}
```

Comment: Darrell, this anwser is so great for you!

Comment: That gives me the response header along with the body.  I *only* want the body. `Optional("HTTP/1.1 OK\nContent-Type: application/json\n\n[{\"foo\":\"bar\"}]")`

Comment: You may need to add headers to your request, ie `["Content-Type":"application/json", "Accept":"application/json"]`

Comment: Tried that (see updated question) but it doesn't appear to have made a difference.

Comment: I took your code and pointed it to a sample json server instead of 127.0.0.1 and I got what I was expecting.  Your server seems to be having trouble generating the response.

Comment: You were able to get only the json without the header?

Comment: Yes.  The only content in `responseData` was the json.  I think the issue is with your server.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks!  I hadn't noticed the problem before because my browsers were handling it somehow.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying your question, but it reads like you're just wanting something as simple as data-to-string conversion.

`let jsonString = String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8)`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to Serialize the response data to get the raw JSON:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (responseData, response, error) in

    // check for errors, then...

    if let resData = responseData {                    
        let jsonResponse = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: resData, options: [])

        if let response = jsonResponse as? [String: Any] {
             // ... handle response
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `dump(resData)` shows 177 bytes but `dump(jsonResponse)` returns `nil`

Comment: have you tried downcasting your serialized json like `try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [[String: Any]]`

Comment: That gives me a "Cast from 'Data?' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails" warning and "Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type '(with: [String : Any], " error.

Comment: Check now @DarrellBrogdon

Comment: `print(response)` doesn't produce anything but I do get `TIC Read Status [2:0x600000165c40]: 1:57` on the console.

Comment: `response` is a `Dictionary` type, `[String: Any]` @DarrellBrogdon - you have to look up your data by key to get the value.

Comment: And `TIC Read Status [2:0x600000165c40]: 1:57` is what we call "Console spew" - ie: output that the developers of XCode use for their own diagnostic purposes. You can read more about that message [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46431730).

Comment: I should have been clearer, my apologies.  `if let response = jsonResponse as? [String: Any] {` appears to evaluate to false.  If I put a `print()` statement in there, it doesn't execute.  If I add an `else` to the `if` statement, with a `print` inside the else, then that is the one that gets executed.

Comment: Sounds like there's an issue deserializing your JSON. Are you sure it's valid JSON being sent?

Comment: This is the raw data coming back:  `"HTTP/1.1 OK\nContent-Type: application/json\n\n{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"`  Unless something internal is striping out the header, then that is what is getting included in the serialization.  But that's my whole point;  I *only* want the JSON as a *string*.  I don't need it to be an object and I don't want the header!  If there is a way of taking that raw data and stripping out the header, then that's fine.