# Firebase / Firestore - completion block not working as expected

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Based on what I have read on the documentation page on Firestore, after I get the document, completion handler (aka the closure) should be called. I have the following code and I am trying to display a field from every document from a collection from Firestore but when I run the app, it doesn't work. The label from every cell isn't changed.

**Later Edit:** Also, scrolling through the tableview is really buggy and when you scroll down and try to scroll up again you it won't go up, it will just shake.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class AnunturiViewController: UITableViewController {

    var anunturi: [Produs] = [Produs]()
    var docRef: DocumentReference!
    var docRefNrTotalProduse: DocumentReference!
    var nrTotalProduse = 0
    var isDone = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ADCell") as! ADTableViewCell
        if isDone == true {
            cell.denumireAnuntLabel.text = anunturi[nrTotalProduse - indexPath.row].denumire
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        docRefNrTotalProduse = Firestore.firestore().collection("nrproduse").document("nrproduse")

        docRefNrTotalProduse.getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error ?? "0") }
            else {
                let data = snapshot?.data()
                self.nrTotalProduse = data!["nrtotalproduse"] as! Int
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

        return nrTotalProduse
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 164.0
    }

    @IBAction func onRefreshButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func fetchData() {
        var i = 0
        while(i < nrTotalProduse) {
            docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("produse").document(String(nrTotalProduse - i))

            docRef.getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
                let data = snapshot?.data()
                let produs = Produs(denumire: (data?["nume"] as? String)!)
                self.anunturi.append(produs)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if i == self.nrTotalProduse - 1 {
                        self.isDone = true
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }

            i += 1
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: one question, the closure is not being called (not executing any line inside the closure) or the tableView is not showing anything?

Comment: The tableview is showing the cells as the prototype that are I have created, but the not with the data from Firebase

Comment: Also, I get a bunch of messages called 'TIC' in the console, what does those mean?

Comment: here is the answer for your later question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352735/what-is-tic-read-status-157-in-ios11-xcode-9

Comment: I also get these errors: Task <803C8E0B-B42E-42F1-8AC5-E4A25B14ADDA>.<2> finished with error - code: -1003
2018-06-14 13:58:10.039638+0300 Hyype[8178:2311609] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
2018-06-14 13:58:10.040701+0300 Hyype[8178:2311609] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: I think the main issue is because `self.isDone = true` is never executed. The reason I think this is because at the time you call `fetchData`, `nrTotalProduse` will always be `0`, so the execution flow will never enter to the while loop.

Second: You see the cells as they look in the prototypes because `numberOfRowsInSection` is being called and returning a number that you set to `nrTotalProduse`, but because the `isDone` variable is never set to `true`, cells are not being set with the corresponding value.

Third: The "buggy" scroll you experience is because what you are calling inside the `numberOfRowsInSection` method. This method will be called whenever you call `tableView.reloadData`, so what you are doing is keeping a loop of calls that will never end inside this method, resulting in a call to `reloadData` such many times that you can even see the scroll.

Totally avoid this kind of calls inside the `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

**Edit:**

If what you are trying to do is get all the documents in the `produse` collection, I strongly recommend changing the `fetchData` method to something like this:

```
func fetchData() {
    docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("produse")
    docRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let produs = Produs(denumire: (data?["nume"] as? String)!)
                self.anunturi.append(produs)
            }

            self.isDone = true
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so, I've changed a few things and so I moved the fetching data to collect nrTotalProduse in viewDidLoad and I set the nrTotalProduse to be a computed property, so when didSet is called, the fetchData function is called. The "buggy" scroll has gone, but still it isn't chaning the label, I've checked with a print statement and now when it enters in fetchData, nrTotalProduse is correct to what I want.

Comment: put a breakpoint at the line `self.isDone = true` to see if `isDone` is being set

Comment: I put also a print and both of them weren't called, so here is the problem, should this be changed to a for loop or the loop is not the problem?