# Parsing Api in swift Error TIC Read Status

Tags: ios, swift, api

I'm working on IOS app in which I'm using localhost Api. Following is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/teams") else {return}
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let dataResponse = data,
            error == nil else {

                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")

                return }
        do{
            //here dataResponse received from a network request
            let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                dataResponse, options: [])

                guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [[String: Any]] else {
                return
            }

            for team in jsonArray{
                guard let name = team["name"] as? String else { return }
                guard let country = team["country"] as? String else{return}
                self.teamName.append(name)
                self.teamCountry.append(country)

                print(name,country) //Output

            }
        } catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
        }
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    task.resume()


}
```

The above code is working fine and I'm getting all data loaded in my tableview.
I want that when user select a row it should call another Api to show more detail of the selected screen on another viewcontroller. But when I call my second Api I get following error:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let DvC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! ViewController
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/team/"+teamName[indexPath.row]) else {return}

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let dataResponse = data,
            error == nil else {

                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")

                return }
        do{
            //here dataResponse received from a network request
            let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                dataResponse, options: [])

              guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [[String: Any]] else {
                return
            }

            guard let name = jsonArray[0]["name"] as? String else { return }
            guard let country = jsonArray[0]["country"] as? String else{ return }
            DvC.getName = name
            DvC.getCountry = country

        } catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
        }

    }
    task.resume()


    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DvC, animated: true)
}
```

In my second Api call am getting error like TeamApiScreen[34251:281435] TIC Read Status [5:0x600000178540]: 1:57

Comment: please any one having solution to this .

Comment: You are calling an API and then navigating to another View Controller, you should do the API call on the other ViewController or wait until it give you response back using some completion handler etc

Comment: By doing API call on the other viewController it works.Thank you Sir

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352735/what-is-tic-read-status-157-in-ios11-xcode-9