# Task finished with error - code: -999 when creating a custom user location annotation on mapbox

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, maps, mapbox

I [installed mapbox into my xcode project using cocoapods](https://www.mapbox.com/install/ios/).

Then I just copied and pasted the [example for creating a custom user location annotation](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/user-location-annotation/) into my view controller.

I get the following errors over and over again.

```
2019-04-20 21:40:17.546153-0600 MapboxExample[17175:6272371] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
2019-04-20 21:40:17.546485-0600 MapboxExample[17175:6272343] Task <77C9CA04-84AD-46F5-856E-E4637746946C>.<41> finished with error - code: -999
```

They seem to happen when I zoom in and out of the map, or sometimes when I move the map.

---

**Code**

The only swift files are **ViewController.swift**, which copied from the [mapbox website](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/user-location-annotation/) exactly

and **AppDelegate.swift**, which was created automatically(I've remove the comments from the AppDelegate).

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {return true}
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {}
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {}
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication){}
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {}
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {}
}
```

---

**Main.storyboard**

[image]

---

**Info.plist**

[image]

---

**Podfile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MapboxExample' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  target 'MapboxExampleTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MapboxExampleUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 4.10'

end
```

---

**Full console log**

```
2019-04-20 21:45:20.825612-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274013] [INFO] {}[General]: GPU Identifier: Apple A9 GPU
2019-04-20 21:45:21.394592-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274104] Task <9CC25959-F233-4CC1-B5C0-CF649B2052B1>.<1> finished with error - code: -999
2019-04-20 21:45:21.394657-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274104] Task <2CAB3355-413C-438B-8553-BA1BF486D2EF>.<2> finished with error - code: -999
2019-04-20 21:45:21.394692-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274105] Task <9CC25959-F233-4CC1-B5C0-CF649B2052B1>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
2019-04-20 21:45:21.575393-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274089] Task <B808E929-D536-40E8-81EA-B2089052C299>.<3> finished with error - code: -999
2019-04-20 21:45:21.575387-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274086] Task <B808E929-D536-40E8-81EA-B2089052C299>.<3> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
2019-04-20 21:45:21.879419-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274104] TIC Read Status [6:0x0]: 1:57
2019-04-20 21:45:21.879950-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274104] Task <BDE867C2-A824-4A38-8858-1CAE3A107F5B>.<4> finished with error - code: -999
2019-04-20 21:45:21.908546-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274104] Task <065B03E7-B3A2-4AE0-BC33-A1D8F7B68F22>.<5> finished with error - code: -999
2019-04-20 21:45:21.908720-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274089] Task <065B03E7-B3A2-4AE0-BC33-A1D8F7B68F22>.<5> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
2019-04-20 21:45:22.758155-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274104] Task <2CF73603-74F4-4259-BA8A-04DAFDA33055>.<6> finished with error - code: -999
2019-04-20 21:45:22.758282-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274089] Task <2CF73603-74F4-4259-BA8A-04DAFDA33055>.<6> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
2019-04-20 21:45:22.974860-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274104] Task <C678C084-B783-4707-B01F-9E8F187D5440>.<7> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
2019-04-20 21:45:22.975577-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274105] Task <C678C084-B783-4707-B01F-9E8F187D5440>.<7> finished with error - code: -999
2019-04-20 21:45:22.976605-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274104] Task <1A1C5883-71B0-4397-A660-D5A6169ECF64>.<8> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
2019-04-20 21:45:22.976629-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274105] Task <1A1C5883-71B0-4397-A660-D5A6169ECF64>.<8> finished with error - code: -999
2019-04-20 21:46:21.437133-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274089] TIC Read Status [1:0x281b4d380]: 1:57
2019-04-20 21:46:21.437321-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274089] TIC Read Status [1:0x281b4d380]: 1:57
2019-04-20 21:46:21.437392-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274089] TIC Read Status [1:0x281b4d380]: 1:57
2019-04-20 21:46:21.440978-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274089] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x1043184c0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-04-20 21:46:21.441310-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274089] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x1043184c0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-04-20 21:46:21.442689-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274089] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-04-20 21:46:21.442758-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274089] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-04-20 21:46:21.442809-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274089] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-04-20 21:46:21.442868-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274089] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-04-20 21:49:21.456402-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274208] TIC Read Status [11:0x281b5e280]: 1:57
2019-04-20 21:49:21.456572-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274208] TIC Read Status [11:0x281b5e280]: 1:57
2019-04-20 21:49:21.456638-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274208] TIC Read Status [11:0x281b5e280]: 1:57
2019-04-20 21:49:21.459631-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274208] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C11.1:2][0x1044a0a80] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-04-20 21:49:21.460091-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274208] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C11.1:2][0x1044a0a80] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-04-20 21:49:21.461548-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274208] TIC Read Status [11:0x0]: 1:57
2019-04-20 21:49:21.461621-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274208] TIC Read Status [11:0x0]: 1:57
2019-04-20 21:49:21.461696-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274208] TIC Read Status [11:0x0]: 1:57
2019-04-20 21:49:21.461752-0600 MapboxExample[17184:6274208] TIC Read Status [11:0x0]: 1:57
```

Comment: I get these all the time. When I originally encountered them I dug around and (I think) I discovered they were simply download commands that were cancelled by the API during zooming, etc. Say you zoom with a slight bias/movement to the right then tiles being downloaded for the left might get cancelled. That cancellation is being reported in the error code which seems a little verbose to me. I treat it as a return code rather than an error code. Unfortunately when I did a quick search just now for my source I couldn’t find it. I’ll try again later when I have more time.

Comment: @Magnas Any luck? What do you mean by return code? Do you actually code something to handle it differently? To me it's just a message that appears in my console so I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: Hib @Jacob - Sorry for the delay. By return code I simply mean a response from the server that isn't an actual error. For example the familiar 200/201 codes that indicate success. I'd assumed they were all just being supplied  under the 'error' banner whether benign or not. Anyway, I did find a couple of related things for the -999 code and it seems I was only partially correct. -999 appears to be a URLErrorCancelled code of the URLSessionTask. I'll post the links here so you can read for yourself. I don't handle them in any special way beyond ignoring them.

Comment: https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/pspdfkit-instant/error-999/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073519/nsurlerrordomain-error-code-999-in-ios/16076142

Comment: @Magnas Do you know a way to squelch the warning at least? I noticed the second link has an objective C answer as the second answer on the question, do you know what that translates to in Swift?

Comment: @Magnas Also, are the TIC read status and boringSSL 8196 errors part of the same problem or are they something different? Do you know anything about those?

Comment: There is a good explanation for the TIC message here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352735/what-is-tic-read-status-157-in-ios11-xcode-9 which basically (again) recommends ignoring it. As for the Objective-C answer, I'm sorry I can't help. It looks like something specific to the OC's question about Facebook/Corona.

Comment: @Magnas and is the boringSSL error also something to be ignored