# Download stops for AWS S3 file with slow Wifi connection

Tags: ios, amazon-s3

I have an app and I am trying to download file which is on AWS S3 and 5mb. I am having no issue with cellular but with comparingly slow wifi (not so slow about 120 kb/s), the download stops about 10%. I was searching a lot and did some motification on info.plist but didn't help. Below you can see what I used in info.plist and logs during download.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>amazonaws.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

log output:

```
2019-06-04 22:17:36.828347+0300 My App [12042:57908] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x7fdd3c72a8e0] get output frames failed, state 8196
```

Comment: Can you show us a code for downloading task?

Comment: @AndreiKonstantinov it is not timeout because it stops about 10th second of download. I tried with redownloadTasksQueue and any other background download code is not working. Unless the file is on normal http domain.

Comment: It works fine via `http` protocol, but fails if it's `https`?

Comment: yes, when I put the file on some http domain it works.

Comment: It is same for simulator and real device. Not only my internet but other users complained it with some slow wifi.

Comment: Thats really all about it because download just pauses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is TIC Read Status 1:57 in iOS11/Xcode 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352735/what-is-tic-read-status-157-in-ios11-xcode-9)

Comment: What command or code are you using to make the download?